# Rails Active Record group or ignore duplicate results from query

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have an active record query which returns a list of tags from search query. I'm rendering that to json to use in a tag search.

The issue is that the query will return multiple tags of the same kind. Is there any ignore multiples or group multiples?

Here's the query (sorry it's quite a long one):

```
Tag.joins("INNER JOIN taggings ON taggings.tag_id = tags.id INNER JOIN posts ON taggings.taggable_id = posts.id INNER JOIN buckets ON posts.bucket_id = buckets.id INNER JOIN memberships ON memberships.bucket_id = buckets.id").where(memberships: {user_id: current_user.id, accepted: true}).where("name LIKE ?" , "#{params[:query]}%")
```

For example, when you search for 'illustration' two posts tagged with illustration are returned and I'd like to group that into just one:

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: `Tag.joins("INNER JOIN taggings ON taggings.tag_id = tags.id INNER JOIN posts ON taggings.taggable_id = posts.id INNER JOIN buckets ON posts.bucket_id = buckets.id INNER JOIN memberships ON memberships.bucket_id = buckets.id").where(memberships: {user_id: current_user.id, accepted: true}).where("name LIKE ?" , "#{params[:query]}%").group('tags.name')`

try this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to chain `.uniq` onto the end of the query to bring back unique records.  Or you could try `.distinct`

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/distinct